# Crystal report4.6.1.0 connection to Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb6, crystal-reports

How to set path to a MySQL database which is installed on another server, e.g. `192.168.1.35`?

```
strReportName = "Schedule.rpt"

intReportDestination = crptToWindow
With rptAnnSalExp
    .ReportFileName = GetAppPath1() & strReportName
    .Destination = intReportDestination
    .Connect = "SERVER=192.168.1.35;DATABASE=test;User=amu; Password=amu"
    rptAnnSalExp.Action = crptMaximized
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string doesn't specify the database provider to use so it has no idea how to connect.
You should be able to use the same connection string that you used to create the normal database connection in code.